# Get all the relations between models including node data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this nodes and relations, but I have a issue regarding the **from** and **to** node info

I have this 3 transactions

- from: 111, to: 222 -> amount: $10000
- from: 222, to: 333 -> amount: $2000
- from: 222, to: 444 -> amount: $4000

With this query (not shure if it's ok)

```
MATCH path = (:Contact {contact_id: '111'})-[t:TRANSACTION*1..3]-()
With relationships(path) as relations
unwind relations as u_relations
With distinct(u_relations) as distinct_relations
return distinct_relations
```

I get the info I need, but I can't figure it out how to add the contact_id from and to of each transaction, the result is

```
{

  "identity": 0,
  "start": 0,
  "end": 1,
  "type": "TRANSACTION",
  "properties": {
    "date": "2023-08-03T17:08:34-03:00",
    "amount": 10000.0
  },
  "elementId": "0",
  "startNodeElementId": "0",
  "endNodeElementId": "1"
}
{
  "identity": 1,
  "start": 1,
  "end": 5,
  "type": "TRANSACTION",
  "properties": {
    "date": "2023-08-03T17:08:34-03:00",
    "amount": 2000.0
  },
  "elementId": "1",
  "startNodeElementId": "1",
  "endNodeElementId": "5"
}
{
  "identity": 2,
  "start": 1,
  "end": 6,
  "type": "TRANSACTION",
  "properties": {
    "date": "2023-08-03T17:08:35-03:00",
    "amount": 4000.0
  },
  "elementId": "2",
  "startNodeElementId": "1",
  "endNodeElementId": "6"
}
```

How can I use **start** and **end** keys to grab the contact_id and add it to the result?

Answer (score 1):

The start and end keys are refering to the Neo4j internal node identifiers, which should not be used outside from Neo4j, as they can change over time.

Your query itself shouldn't require using those; the following query should work:

```
MATCH (c:Contact {contact_id: '111'})-[t:TRANSACTION*1..3]-()
RETURN c, t
```

Using distinct(t) is not required, as Neo4j does not the same relation twice inside a single path.

Comment: Actually, variable-length relationship queries are a special case. They can return the same relationship multiple times, since the same relationship can exist in paths of incrementally greater lengths.

Comment: @cybersam oh really? that's quite interesting to know, thx

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
MATCH (:Contact {contact_id: '111'})-[rs:TRANSACTION*..3]-()
UNWIND rs AS r
WITH DISTINCT
  STARTNODE(r).contact_id AS from,
  ENDNODE(r).contact_id AS to,
  r
WITH from, to, COLLECT(r.amount) AS amounts
RETURN COLLECT({from: from, to: to, amounts: amounts}) AS result
```

This query gets all distinct relationships for each `from/to` pair, collects the `amount` values for each pair, and then returns all the results in a single list.

Note: If N relationships for the same pair have the same `amount`, then that `amount` will appear N times in the `transactions` list for that pair. I presume this is what you wanted.

The results should look something like this:

```
[
{ 
    from: '111',
    to: '222',
    amounts: [10000]
},
{ 
    from: '222',
    to: '333',
    amounts: [2000]
},
{ 
    from: '222',
    to: '444',
    amounts: [4000]
}
]
```